# Android Studio kaptDebugKoltin internal compiler error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

My kotlin android project just stops to build and run. I don't know what went wrong, but some days ago everything was fine. Now on rebuild it says following:

[image]
Logs contains following:

```
2017-09-18 08:20:17,691 [ 870125]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from D:/progs/Android Studio/jre 
2017-09-18 08:20:17,752 [ 870186]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\User2\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo5085.gradle] 
2017-09-18 08:20:17,753 [ 870187]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\User2\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo5085.gradle] 
2017-09-18 08:20:37,451 [ 889885]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.<init>(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList) 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.<init>(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:143)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.getSimpleMessageConstructor(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createNewMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:272)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:250)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage$default(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:244)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelperKt.parse(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParser.parse(KotlinOutputParser.java:28)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.ToolOutputParser.parseToolOutput(ToolOutputParser.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.output.parser.BuildOutputParser.parseGradleOutput(BuildOutputParser.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor$GradleTasksExecutorImpl.lambda$collectMessages$5(GradleTasksExecutor.java:516)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-09-18 08:20:37,452 [ 889886]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - Exception from KotlinOutputParser 
2017-09-18 08:20:37,482 [ 889916]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-09-18 08:20:37,724 [ 890158]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 99ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-09-18 08:20:37,741 [ 890175]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 17ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-09-18 08:20:37,741 [ 890175]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 30 files to update 
2017-09-18 08:20:38,005 [ 890439]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 264ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in gradle. There was only one needed line.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Now I added android plugin line. Everything now builds as it should.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: Could you clarify your answer ? What is working ? First or second snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case helps "Build -> Clean Project" and "Build -> Rebuild Project"