# java.io.ioexception error=13 permission denied in android studio with internal compiler error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to clone an android project from github, every time i build the project it gives me that error:

> java.io.ioexception error=13 permission denied
>
> > Execution failed for this task : projectname.KaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin.

i ran a gradle clean command then assembleDebug , it built successfully but i still have this error.

i tried the solution in this answer, but it didn't work :-

[android studio kapt debug koltin internal compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271621/android-studio-kaptdebugkoltin-internal-compiler-error)

Any thoughts?

[Logcat Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX9jE.png)

Comment: check your arraylist size, if possible share code

Comment: the project doesn't contain an array list , here is the project
[project](https://github.com/RxMuhammadyoussef/Quora)

Comment: what is your line no.260

Comment: when i click the no.260 it goes ArrayList<E> class  'Not writable file' and there is a message that appear
decompiled .class file bytecode version :52.0 (java 8)
Sources for 'Android API 26 Platform ' not found

Comment: can you please github link for this project

Comment: https://github.com/RxMuhammadyoussef/Quora